# switch on wifi in emulator

Tags: android

I'm doing project on android chat application with both friends and anonymous. we finished with the design phase. now we need to create a network between two emulators present in two system so that we can do chat in two different systems. But in emulator wifi is not getting turned on. I tried with the F8 button still the wifi is not getting on. I'll be grateful for any help in regard of this.if wifi cant be turned on how to simulate the chat application in emulators.we have written server and client side program in java, but don know how to connect server and client Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use real device, because emulators don't support Wifi functionality afaik.

Comment: we cant simulate chatting application in emulators?

Comment: if through direct Internet, it's possible; but with Wifi on emulator, I'm afraid not.

Comment: we are getting internet connection in emulator